# How do I access random elements from a vector in R studio?

Tags: r

Lets say I have a vector c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) how can I get a print of just 1,3,and 5 ?

Comment: You can use square brackets for indexing. `x <- 1:9; x[c(1,3,5)]`

Comment: What is random here?

Comment: By random I meant any element from the sequence, I must have framed it better but this is all I could get .

Comment: The square bracket did help thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a sample of `n` random elements from vector `X` you can use `sample(x = X, size = 3, replace = FALSE)`. To get the `i`th element of `X` you simply use `X[i]`.

Comment: Why `replace = TRUE`?

Comment: You're right, I was thinking FALSE and wrote TRUE. I'll correct now.

Comment: You don't need to write it, it is the default.

Comment: True, but when sampling, as I tend to sometimes need with and without, I think it is good practice to explicitly state it to ensure I'm doing the right thing. Except when I mix them up, of course :)

Comment: That might be the exact reason for not explicitly state them then :)

Comment: I sometimes think of it like `replace` not present --> no replacement